# Acumatica - How to update custom field in Customer Location from custom field in Customer

Tags: events, customization, acumatica

I've tried a few different ways to do this and each way has a piece of code I am just not getting right.  I need to update a custom field UsrCustomerShipAccount in Customer Locations if it is updated in the Customer Delivery Tab.  I tried SetValueExt and creating a graph instance.  Sorry about the dumb question. 
The way that seemed to get me the closest is below:

```
protected void LocationExtAddress_UsrCustomerShipAccnt_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
    if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
    var row = (LocationExtAddress)e.Row;

    if (row == null) return;

    PXSelectBase<Location> locationObj = new PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>>(Base);
    Location deliveryLocation = locationObj.Select(row.LocationBAccountID);
    var locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(location);  <-- This generates error that there is no LocationExt.

    deliveryLocation.Cache.SetValueExt(deliveryLocation, "UsrCustomerShipAccount", -->This needs to be the value that changed LocationExtAddress.UsrCustomerShipAccount but I don't see how to get this<--);
    deliveryLocation.Cache.IsDirty = true;
    deliveryLocation.Update(deliveryLocation);  <--I don't know if this doesn't work because it is wrong or if it is because "UsrCustomerShipAccount" is not in deliverLocation.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
var locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(location);
```

shouldn't this be

```
var locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(deliveryLocation );
```

?

Comment: That was a small part of it...I had it correct it in an earlier version.  I still get an error that LocationExt does not exists.  
            Location delivery = locationObj.Select(row.LocationBAccountID);
            var locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(delivery);

          //  Base.SetValueExt(locationExt, "UsrCustomerShipAccount");

Comment: Ran out of time.  That was a small part of it...I had it correct it in an earlier version.  I still get an error that LocationExt does not exists.  
            Location delivery = locationObj.Select(row.LocationBAccountID);
            var locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(delivery);

Comment: You should check in your code if you get a Location=null and a check to see if locationExt =null.  I would switch to    Location locationExt = PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>.Select(this,row.LocationBAccountID)